# Capturing leaves.length value from d3.nest

Tags: d3.js

Here is the sample data from a tsv file:

```
college dept    year
College of Education, Health & Human Development    Education.  2011
College of Letters & Science    Earth Sciences. 2010
College of Letters & Science    Microbiology & Immunology.  2004
College of Letters & Science    Ecology.    1984
College of Letters & Science    Chemistry & Biochemistry.   2008
College of Letters & Science    Mathematical Sciences.  2011
College of Agriculture  Land Resources & Environmental Sciences.    2009
College of Agriculture  Agricultural Economics & Economics. 1996
College of Letters & Science    English.    2007
College of Letters & Science    Cell Biology & Neuroscience.    2011
College of Agriculture  Land Resources & Environmental Sciences.    2012
Graduate School Intercollege Programs for Science Education.    2012
Graduate School Intercollege Programs for Science Education.    2011
College of Engineering  Mechanical & Industrial Engineering.    2007
College of Engineering  Industrial Engineering. 2005
College of Agriculture  Agricultural Economics & Economics. 1986
College of Nursing  Nursing.    2007
College of Letters & Science    Microbiology & Immunology.  2006
College of Agriculture  Agricultural Economics & Economics. 1974
```

I am using d3.nest as follows:

```
  var deptYearCount = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.college;} )
    .key(function(d) { return d.dept })
    .key(function(d) { return d.year })
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length;})
        .entries(dataset);
```

And am trying to draw circles of radius according to the count by year:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(deptYearCount)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.values*1.5;})
      .style("opacity", 0.3)
      .style("fill", "#e31a1c" )
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.dept); });
```

d.values is returning NaN parsing r attribute. I have tried getting at this value a variety of ways but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d.values` is an array.

So instead of this:

```
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.values*1.5;})
```

you should be doing this since you want to *calculate  radius according to the count by year*:

```
.attr("r", function(d) {return d.values.length*1.5;})
```

Comment: Yes thank you that worked, of course now I am getting undefined for d.dept and d.year... I'll get that sorted out.