# Would like to use length (from d3.nest) as radius

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a mental block about using the result of:

```
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length;})
```

as the radius of a circle in a scatter plot. My complete code (and sample data) is in a plunk here https://plnkr.co/edit/Cwuce6inLV5jouCWTFfN

The scatter works with a static value of 5 but I'd like to use value based on the .rollup from the d3.nest as explained in this other SO question I had: [Capturing leaves.length value from d3.nest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449339/capturing-leaves-length-value-from-d3-nest/37449926#37449926)

I think I'm missing a key concept about in this section of code:

```
d3.tsv("etds_small.tsv", function(error, dataset) {
  dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    if(deptlist.indexOf(d.dept) == -1) deptlist.push(d.dept);
    if(years.indexOf(d.year) == -1) years.push(d.year);
  })

  var deptYearCount = d3.nest()
    //.key(function(d) { return d.college;} )
    .key(function(d) { return d.dept})
    .key(function(d) { return d.year })
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length;})
        .map(dataset);

        console.log(dataset);   // retains the college, dept, and year labels
        console.log(deptYearCount);  // replaces labels with "key"

  x.domain(years.sort(d3.ascending));
  y.domain(deptlist.sort(d3.ascending));
  //console.log(y.domain());
  //console.log(x.domain());

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
          .data(dataset)  //should this be deptYearCount from the d3.nest above?
        .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "dot")
          .attr("r", 5)  // Would like to use length (from d3.nest) as radius
          //.attr("r", function(d) {return d.values.length*1.5;}) works with .data(debtYearCount)
          .style("opacity", 0.3)
          .style("fill", "#e31a1c" )
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return x(d.year);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return y(d.dept);
          });
```

Comment: Interesting. What is the radius supposed to represent?

Comment: Larger circles would indicate more papers per dept in that particular year. I would also use the corresponding value in a tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try for your radius:

```
.attr("r", function(d) {return Object.keys(deptYearCount[d.dept]).length*1.5;})
```

Because you are using `.map(dataset)` instead of `.entries(dataset)`, d3.next() is returning one-big-object instead of an array of objects. That one-big-object does not contain a property called `values`.

Updated explanation:

First, look at the structure of the object `deptYearCount`. It has property names like `Earth Sciences.`, `Education.`, etc.

Our d3 data is iterating over an array of objects. Each object has property `dept` that looks like `Earth Sciences.`, `Education.`, etc.

So, `deptYearCount[d.dept]` is getting us to the correct property within `deptYearCount`.

For example, at one round of our iteration we are looking at `deptYearCount["Education."]`. That turns out to be another object with properties like `2007`,`2008`, etc. Therefore, the number of properties in `deptYearCount["Education."]` is the value we want for the radius.

How do we find the number of properties of `deptYearCount["Education."]`? One way is the `Object.keys(someObject)` function. It returns an array of strings corresonding to the property names, and we just need its `.length`.

Comment: Worked like a champ! Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind walking me through bit of code and why it works? Object.keys(deptYearCount[d.dept])

Comment: @mutanthumb If this is online somewhere, could you share it?